# limiting probability inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, probability-distributions

Let $\{a_i(x)\}_{i=1}^n$ and $\{b_i(x)\}_{i=1}^n$, with $x\in R^m$ be i.i.d random vectors, such that
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty}a_i\to N(0,1), \textit{and} \lim_{x\to \infty}b_i\to N(0,1), \quad i=1, \ldots, n.\quad (1)
$$
Let $\Phi(\alpha)$ denote a standard normal distribution function, where $\alpha$ denotes the significance level.

I am trying to find bound of

$$
\lim_{n,x\to \infty}P(max\{\{a_i(x)\}_{i=1}^n, \{b_i(x)\}_{i=1}^n\}> \frac{1}{\Phi})
$$

So far, I arrived to
$$
P(max\{\{a_i(x)\}_{i=1}^n, \{b_i(x)\}_{i=1}^n\leq \frac{1}{\Phi}\}=\prod_{i=1}^nP(a_i\leq\frac{1}{\Phi})P(b_i\leq\frac{1}{\Phi}).
$$
But now I am stuck, as condition (1) says that each $a_i$ and $b_i$ converges to $N(0,1)$ and I have $1/\Phi$ in the inequality...

Comment: The last product you have written is for $P(\min\{\cdots\} > 1/\Phi)$, not $\max$.

Comment: Thank you, inequality should be reverced.